Iaito dissasembler shows invalid instructions
I am using iaito (official graphical interface for radare2) dissasembler here is an example instruction
0x1400371d4      xor      cl,     cl
0x1400371d6      invalid
0x1400371d7      shl      eax,    0x6f
;-- str.oJ:
0x1400371d9          .string "oJ{\xe5\xa5\x97" ; len=7
0x1400371e0      or       esi,    eax
0x1400371e2      hlt
0x1400371e3      hlt
0x1400371e4      xor      al,     0x23                      ; 35
0x1400371e6      mov      edi,    0xbfbd17fa
0x1400371eb      hlt
0x1400371ec      fisubr   dword [0x1a4ad7568]
0x1400371f2      invalid
0x1400371f3      jrcxz    0x1400371e6                       ; unlikely
0x1400371f5      cmp      byte [rdi + rdi*2],  dl
0x1400371f8      xchg     edx,    eax
0x1400371f9      mov      esp,    0xa05ee3f0
0x1400371fe      hlt
0x1400371ff      invalid
0x140037200      invalid
0x140037201      invalid
0x140037202      invalid
0x140037203      iretd
0x140037204      rcr      dword [rax],  1
0x140037206      scasb    al,     byte [rdi]
0x140037207      invalid


the invalid is not an actual assembly instruction yet for some reason iaito is showing that, but when I am using x64dbg I dont seem to see those "invalid" instructions? any reasons why?
because of these invalid instructions i am not able to emulate the application in Iaito
Previously I was using cutter which had the same problem, so I switched to Iaito which was the original disassembler cutter was built on. Some sections were fixed however some sections still have invalid instructions.

If you try to disassemble something that is not actually assembler code you will get nonsensical gibberish output. You also get nonsense if you don't start out with the right byte alignment. Most debuggers start from an entry point and disassemble as they go. It might be worth displaying the raw hex bytes to see what is actually there.
